# Dark theme flashing when changing page

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to create a dark theme to my website, I choosed to do this thought CSS variables and JS. Everything is fine, but when website restart or changing page, the dark mode flash on a moment and turns back a light theme. Please help with solution. Cache is disabled and I tried everything what were in internet. I think that the problem is in JS code. I'm noob in JavaScript, in learning process. Thank you.

```
// function to set a given theme/color-scheme
function setTheme(themeName) {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
    document.documentElement.className = themeName;
    document.getElementById("sunimgid");
}

// function to toggle between light and dark theme
function toggleTheme() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
        setTheme('theme-light');
        document.getElementById("sunimgid").setAttribute("src", "link");
    } else {
        setTheme('theme-dark');
        document.getElementById("sunimgid").setAttribute("src", "link");
    }
}

// Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
        setTheme('theme-dark');
        document.getElementById("sunimgid").setAttribute("src", "link");
    } else {
        setTheme('theme-light');
        document.getElementById("sunimgid").setAttribute("src", "link");
    }
})();
```

You can check the same problem on http://torrent-mania.net/ (click on the sun, turn on dark theme) and try surfing the site.

Comment: Nice site. Well done. .... As for your problem, you could wrap the body content of the site with a `div` that has `display:none`; then after you do your theme load, set that `div` to `display:block`. In this way the default "theme" doesn't display/flicker in unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand exactly how to do it. Could you give me an example of the code please?

Comment: Ok. It will be a partial answer as I don't have all your code. But it will express the idea.

Comment: view-source:http://torrent-mania.net/
Isn't that it?

Comment: Hey, the third line of the `setTheme` function is really useless.

Comment: Yeah SnugElf, but I dont know if that's rendered by a backend. But anyway, I posted an answer below to express what I meant in code form.

Comment: Thank you so much, but maybe it's because I have a site on Data Life Engine?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I have to insert the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/dark.js"></script>
```

at the top of the page, right after body tag.
I, like a idiot, put a line at the end of the code.

Before:

```
<body>
...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/dark.js"></script>
</body>
```

After:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/dark.js"></script>
    {AJAX}
    ...
</body>
```

Sorry for wasting your time :(